# Including count = zero results in SQL count query

Tags: sql, count

I am counting the number of jobs posted in each empworksite for a specific employer but this query does not show me the empworksites where count = zero. Full, left, and right joins don't help. Any suggestions?

```
select distinct
emp.company,
emp.col_empid,
emp.siccode,
empworksite.location,
empworksite.city,
empworksite.zip,
empworksite.worksiteid,
(select distinct
    count (location)
    from joborders
    where joborders.location = empworksite.worksiteid) as count_of_jobpostings
from empworksite
join emp WITH (NOLOCK) on emp.col_empid = empworksite.col_empid
left join joborders WITH (NOLOCK) on joborders.location = empworksite.worksiteid
WHERE emp.col_empid = '1214763'
AND empworksite.lwia = '14'
AND joborders.createdate > '09/30/2023 23:59'
GROUP By
emp.company,
emp.col_empid,
emp.siccode,
empworksite.location,
empworksite.city,
empworksite.zip,
empworksite.worksiteid
ORDER By count_of_jobpostings DESC
```

please refer to the above example..

Comment: Why `WITH (NOLOCK)` all over?

Comment: does it make a difference?

Comment: No need for the GROUP BY here.

Comment: And you can skip the LEFT JOIN too, the correlated subquery is enough. Perhaps it needs the createdate condition though.

Comment: However, the query is odd on many ways. A [mcve] would make this clearer.

Comment: @Dave_G [It sure does.](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/groups/data-driven/b/blog/posts/bad-habits-putting-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: thank you jarlh, but those suggestions don't give me the count = zero empworksites..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you have a `WHERE` clause on `joborders`, which implicitly turns the left-join into an inner-join. Instead that condition should have been in the `ON` clause.

But you can also simplify this query significantly. There is no need to left-join `joborders` anyway, as you have a separate correlated subquery for that. So you can move the condition into the subquery, and remove the left-join completely. This now allows you to remove the unnecessary `GROUP BY`.

Also

- Don't just throw `DISTINCT` at stuff until it works. Think about *why* you are getting duplicates in the first place, most likely because your joins are wrong.
- Don't use `NOLOCK`, it has serious data integrity implications, and is not a go-faster switch.

```sql
SELECT
  emp.company,
  emp.col_empid,
  emp.siccode,
  ws.location,
  ws.city,
  ws.zip,
  ws.worksiteid,
  (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM joborders jo
    WHERE jo.location = ws.worksiteid
      AND jo.createdate >= '2023-10-01 00:00:00'
  ) as count_of_jobpostings
FROM empworksite ws
JOIN emp ON emp.col_empid = ws.col_empid
WHERE emp.col_empid = '1214763'
  AND ws.lwia = '14'
ORDER By
  count_of_jobpostings DESC;
```

Another solution is a pre-aggregated join.

```sql
SELECT
  emp.company,
  emp.col_empid,
  emp.siccode,
  ws.location,
  ws.city,
  ws.zip,
  ws.worksiteid,
  ISNULL(jo.count_of_jobpostings, 0) as count_of_jobpostings
FROM empworksite ws
JOIN emp ON emp.col_empid = ws.col_empid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      jo.location,
      count(*) as count_of_jobpostings
    FROM joborders jo
    WHERE jo.createdate >= '2023-10-01 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY
      jo.location
) jo ON jo.location = ws.worksiteid
WHERE emp.col_empid = '1214763'
  AND ws.lwia = '14'
ORDER By
  count_of_jobpostings DESC;
```